# C Tree root cannot be traversed twice

Tags: c, pointers

I cant traverse the tree more than once, its seems my a root node which is pointer to tree struct, is incremented and traversed to the end, therefore when I try to traverse it again, its pointed to the last tree node.

This is very odd, as I understood a copy of my pointer is passed in the function.

I'm making a new pointer in the function called "tree * cur" and traversing/manipulating that and not the actual root.

**Struct definition:**

```
 /*
     *  kd tree
     */
    typedef struct tree_
    {
        struct tree *left; 
        struct tree *right; 
        float * info;  
        float distance_to_neighbor;
    } tree;
```

**Here is my relevant Main entry code:**

```
 //1st time is called knn
   printf("knn (k nearest neighboor)\n using n nearest neighbors :");
      n_nearests = access_kd_processing_heap();

    int result_size = knn(root, query_point, 0, k_dimensions, query_size, n_nearests);

 current_tree = n_nearests;
    info=NULL;
    distance=0.0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < result_size ; i++)
    {
        printf ("{");
        for (int c = 0; c < k_dimensions ; c++)
        {
             info = (float *)current_tree[i]->info;

            if (NULL !=   info )
            {

                printf ("%f,", info[c]);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }//end for 
        printf ("} ");
        distance =  (float)current_tree[i]->distance_to_neighbor; 
        printf ("min_distance=%f\n",distance);

   }//end for 


 printf("knn (k nearest neighboor)\n using n nearest neighbors :");
      n_nearests = access_kd_processing_heap();
    //2nd time knn is called 
    result_size = knn(root, query_point, 0, k_dimensions, query_size, n_nearests);

 current_tree = n_nearests;
    info=NULL;
    distance=0.0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < result_size ; i++)
    {
        printf ("{");
        for (int c = 0; c < k_dimensions ; c++)
        {
             info = (float *)current_tree[i]->info;

            if (NULL !=   info )
            {

                printf ("%f,", info[c]);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }//end for 
        printf ("} ");
        distance =  (float)current_tree[i]->distance_to_neighbor; 
        printf ("min_distance=%f\n",distance);

   }//end for
```

**Actual knn code:**

```
 int
knn (tree* root, float data_point[], int depth, const int k_dimensions,
     int number_of_nearest_neighbors, tree** n_nearests)
{
    /* use the static processing space to avoid defining a potentially huge
        array on the stack */
    tree** all_nearests = access_kd_processing_heap ();

    int nearest_counter = 0;
    if (root != NULL && n_nearests != NULL)
    {

        //now lets traverse the tree inorder & calculate distances  
        //from the query point  
        tree * cur = root;

        tree * pre;
        while (NULL != cur)
        {
            if (NULL == cur->left)
            {


                cur->distance_to_neighbor =
                        n_dimensional_euclidean (data_point, cur->info);

                all_nearests[nearest_counter] = cur;

                nearest_counter++;

                cur = cur->right; // move to next right node

            }
            else
            {
                pre = cur->left;
                while (pre->right != NULL && pre->right != cur)
                { // find rightmost
                    pre = pre->right;
                }

                /* Make current as the right child of its inorder  
             predecessor */
                if (pre->right == NULL)
                {
                    pre->right = cur;
                    cur = cur->left;
                }

                else
                {

                    pre->right = NULL;
                    //                     //calculate distance 
                    cur->distance_to_neighbor = n_dimensional_euclidean
                            (data_point, cur->info);
                    all_nearests[nearest_counter] = cur;

                    nearest_counter++;
                    cur = cur->right;

                }
            }
        }//end while

        //sort based on distance from query point 
        quick_sort_based_on_distance (*all_nearests, 0, nearest_counter - 1);

        // return only specified number_of_nearest_neighbors
        // do NOT return elements beyond nearest_counter
        if (number_of_nearest_neighbors > nearest_counter)
            number_of_nearest_neighbors = nearest_counter;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_nearest_neighbors; i++)
        {
            n_nearests[i] = all_nearests[i];
            n_nearests[i]->distance_to_neighbor =
                    all_nearests[i]->distance_to_neighbor;
            n_nearests[i]->info = all_nearests[i]->info;
            n_nearests[i]->left = all_nearests[i]->left;
            n_nearests[i]->right = n_nearests[i]->right;
        }

        //JUST FOR DEBUGGING START        
        printf ("***Root After KNN search :\n");
        printf ("***DEBUGGING START\n");
        printf ("{");
        for (int c = 0; c < k_dimensions; c++)
        {

            if (NULL != root->info)
            {
                printf ("%f,", root->info[c]);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }//end for 
        printf ("} ");
        printf ("min_distance=%f\n", root->distance_to_neighbor);
        printf ("***DEBUGGING END\n");
        //JUST FOR DEBUGGING END

        return number_of_nearest_neighbors;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Error, knn input parameter error");
        return -1;
    }
}//end function
```

**Console output:**

```
 knn (k nearest neighboor)
 using n nearest neighbors :3 nearest neighbors to Key: {3.000000,3.000000,3.000000}
knn (k nearest neighboor)
 using n nearest neighbors :
***Root Before KNN search :
***DEBUGGING START
{-3.000000,-3.000000,-3.000000,} min_distance=0.000000
***DEBUGGING END
***Root After KNN search :
***DEBUGGING START
{3.000000,3.000000,3.000000,} min_distance=0.000000
***DEBUGGING END
{3.000000,3.000000,3.000000,} min_distance=0.000000
{4.000000,4.000000,4.000000,} min_distance=1.000000
{2.000000,2.000000,2.000000,} min_distance=1.000000
```

How can I prevent the root from being affected by the function so the tree can be traversed  many times?

Much appreciated.

Comment: From the source I don't see any instruction that changes `root`. You might like to use printf-debugging to make sure that your assumption is true. Please provide a [example] for deeper inspection. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee, yes I added extra debugging  code & root is changing before & after the knn operation which is mysterious.

Comment: I actually removed knn & performed a recursive inorder traversal, & printfed root befotre & after and the root had NOT changed. Which means my implementation of the Morris traversal is somehow in fact change the root, ALTHOUGH the root is passed to an internal pointer in the function.

Comment: Well, you're one or more steps closer to the problem but not yet there, I think. But as I asked for, would you please be so kind to post a [example] that can be compiled by us? We need to run and debug the code ourselves to go deeper.